# How to copy .mdf and .ldf files from one location to another while the application is still open?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection, database-backups, mysql-backup

I have created an application that stores & query data using SQL Database. Everything is ok but just the problem is Backing it up, and after a lot of Searching I found two ways of Backup. First, using the command `"use [Database Name] Backup database [Database Name] To Disk='[Backup Location]'`. But problem with this method is it required SSM software to be be installed on the machine but I don't want it to be installed as it would allow the user to have more control then he need for that Database file, so if anybody can give me solution for this it would be really helpful. And the Second method is Copying the .mdf file and .ldf file, but problem is I cannot copy those files directly from the application or even indirectly if the application is opened and we can copy that only when we close the app but I don't want that and my main question focuses on this issue.

My Question.
How can I copy these files from the default location to backup location using VB.Net coding directly from the application without closing it? Is there anyway to close the connection to these files?

Note: I tried `Connection.Close()` and `Connection.Dispose()`

Comment: You don't need SSMS to do a backup.
See [Using Transact-SQL here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187510.aspx)

Comment: Example of Using Transact-SQL is : 
- - - - -     'USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012  
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'  
   WITH FORMAT,  
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',  
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2012';  
GO'               - - - - 
Here what should I replace with "AdventureWorks2012"

Comment: your database name

Comment: Imagine my Database name is DataDB but just replacing with DataDB won't do anything but will show error because I didn't mentioned the location of the Database and this is what I was actually asking...

Comment: Also you have tagged this with mysql etc but your question refers to .mdf & .ldf files and SSMS, which would indicate MS SQL Server - which is what I assumed in my comment.

Comment: So I should not use MySQL should I change it to MySQL-Server? & Please can you help me with my question...?

Comment: Ok guys good news! I'm sharing the answer..... I found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so before answering the question let me say something, most of us know and has seen at many websites that the **Second Method (Copying the .mdf and .ldf file)** is the least safe way and can cause terrible issue and the **First Method (Using Transact-SQL for Backup/ Restore)** is more preferable and convenient along with more safer method. But I guess many people (Especially beginners like me) would have problem with the query `use [DatabaseName] Backup database [DatabaseName] To Disk='[Backup Location]'` because the Database is consisted of two files (.mdf and .ldf) so how can this two files could be used with this code. And the solution I found is adding `initial catalog = [DatabaseName]` to my ConnectionString, check the following code:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + My.Settings.DBLocation + ";initial catalog=InvoiceDB;Integrated Security=True"

Sub Backup_Click()
    With SaveFileDialogue2
        .Title = "Select Backup Location"
        .Filter = "BAK File Only|*.bak"
        .FileName = "Backup " + Format(Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"))
        If SaveFileDialogue2.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            If .FileName <> "" Then
                Dim BackupQuery As String
                BackupQuery = "Backup database [DatabaseName] To Disk='" + .FileName + "'"
                Using conn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                        With comm
                            .Connection = conn
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = BackupQuery
                        End With
                        Try
                            conn.Open()
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            MsgBox("Backup Completed!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Successful")
                            conn.Close()
                        Catch ex As SqlException
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
                        Finally
                            conn.Dispose()
                        End Try
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

and VOILA it worked! So if anyone else have the same problem you can try this one....

Note: Change [DatabaseName] to your Database Name and remove "[ ]" too. And I added this answer to another question as they are similar so you can follow anyone. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323392/how-to-create-a-database-without-ssms) to go to the other question.